# Explaining this recursive call to sumil up the values of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, javascript-objects

Hy guys, I recently started learning JavaScript and I got to recursion. I saw a recursive function that I don't really understand what's going on behind the hood, please can some help me by explaining how this function worked

```
let company = {
  sales: [{
    name: 'John',
    salary: 1000
  }, {
    name: 'Alice',
    salary: 1600
  }],

  development: {
    sites: [{
      name: 'Peter',
      salary: 2000
    }, {
      name: 'Alex',
      salary: 1800
    }],

    internals: [{
      name: 'Jack',
      salary: 1300
    }]
  }
};
```

The recursive function

```
function sumSalaries(department) {
  if (Array.isArray(department)) { // case (1)
    return department.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.salary, 0); // sum the array
  } else { // case (2)
    let sum = 0;
    for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
      sum += sumSalaries(subdep); //(line*) recursively call for subdepartments, sum the results 
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Why was the recursive call made in line* and not anywhere else.

Comment: There is really no reason to use recursion in that since it is not deeply nested.

Comment: @epascarello: sure for that specific example.  But the function as supplied will work equally well on input with departments nested in divisions nested in lines of business nested in child companies nested in companies nested in conglomerates.

Comment: @epascarello The example very much appears arbitrarily nested, note that the development teams has nested sub-teams but the sales team doesn't.

Comment: "*Why was the recursive call made in the marked line and not anywhere else?*" - uh, where else could it have been made?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is an array it is the **base case** for you just have to sum all the values of salary:

```
  sales: [{
    name: 'John',
    salary: 1000
  }, {
    name: 'Alice',
    salary: 1600
  }]
```

Like this:

```
return department.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.salary, 0); // sum the array
```

However, if it's an object then the **recursion** takes place, and sums all the children of it.

```
let sum = 0;
for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
  sum += sumSalaries(subdep); //(line*) recursively call for subdepartments, sum the results 
}
return sum;
```

Comment: And let's note that with a simple `sum` helper, we can write this as `const sumSalaries = (o) => Array .isArray (o) ? sum (o .map ((p) => p .salary)) : sum (Object .values (o) .map (sumSalaries))`.